# SQL Server - Alter Index reorg or rebuild to change fill factor

Tags: sql-server

If I change the fill factor of an index, to make the change effective do I have to rebuild the index using "alter index rebuild" or can I also use "alter index reorganise"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use rebuild. Reorganise simply removes unused space and does some page defragmentation.

Comment: Thanks, though that was the case - good to get comformation :)